# How to remove multiple parameter url using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a function to remove more than 1 parameters without reloading with replaceState. I have created a function below, and this function works but only for 1 parameter.

If on another page I have more than 1 parameter that I want to remove, how do I do that? I want this functionality to work for all pages. Can anyone help me?

```js
function removeURLParameter(url, parameter) {
    var urlparts = url.split('?');  
 
    if (urlparts.length >= 2) {

       var prefix = encodeURIComponent(parameter) + '=';
       var pars = urlparts[1].split(/[&;]/g);

       for (var i = pars.length; i-- > 0;) {    
          if (pars[i].lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== -1) {  
             pars.splice(i, 1);
          }
       }

       return urlparts[0] + (pars.length > 0 ? '?' + pars.join('&') : '');
    }
    return url;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  const url = "http://localhost:8088/products/10?param1=key1&param2=key2&param3=key3&param4=key4"
  const removeURLParams = removeURLParameter( url, 'param3')
  
  console.log(url)
  console.log(removeURLParams)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a much simpler approach:

You can use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to allow your function to accept multiple parameters.

To remove the parameters, you can first parse the URL with the [`URL` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL), then get its `searchParams` property. Then, loop through each parameter and use [`URLSearchParams.delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/delete) to delete the parameter.

```js
function removeURLParameters(url, ...parameters) {
    const parsed = new URL(url);
    parameters.forEach(e => parsed.searchParams.delete(e))
    return parsed.toString()
}

const url = "http://localhost:8088/products/10?param1=key1&param2=key2&param3=key3&param4=key4"

const res = removeURLParameters(url, 'param1', 'param3')

console.log(res)
```

Comment: I see that the return has a ```parsed.protocol + '//' + parsed.host + parsed.pathname```. Seems like this only applies to localhost? what if I have a live website?

Comment: @frankfurt It will work for any valid URL.

Comment: Ah i see... i tried to remove all parameters from this url ```http://localhost:8088/products/10?param1=key1&param2=key2&param3=key3&param4=key4```, but still there is "?" at the end of the pathname ```http://localhost:8088/products/10?```. what if all parameters remove "?" also gone? so that the url looks nice like this ```http://localhost:8088/products/10```